# Représentation du nom déverbal de langue anglaise : l'exemple du « tailgating » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

En anglais on a le [*tailgate party*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailgate_party) qu'on peut traduire par [*fête d'avant-partie/match*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8370365/fete-davant-partie) (GDT) et on peut avoir le verbe *to tailgate* par ellipse de *party* ainsi que le [nom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tailgating) déverbal « tailgat[**ing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing) » :

> Le *tailgating* implique généralement la consommation de boissons alcoolisées ou de sodas et la cuisson de viande.
> Le *tailgating* s'est ensuite étendu à d'autres festivités d'avant-match lors d'événements sportifs tels que...
>
> [ Exemples de phrases tirées de l'article Wikipédia ]

Le deuxième exemple illustre mieux la nuance entre le nom *tailgate party* et le déverbal *tailgating* dénotant le verbe et son abstraction en substantif.

- Par quoi peut-on remplacer *tailgating* (...compléter/remanier *fête
  d'avant-partie/match*) dans les exemples pour obtenir un équivalent en
  français et pourquoi ?
- Pourquoi pense-t-on ou non que ce sera utile dans toutes les
  situations où l'on traduira un nom déverbal de langue anglaise ?

Je ne cherche pas des synonymes mais bien un tour qui encapsule *tailgate party* ou son équivalent dans une formulation/substantivation plus abstraite dans le contexte des phrases sur Wikipédia ou plus généralement.

Comment: Un avant-match festif ? Un échauffement de supporters joyeusement arrosé ? Un plaisir malin/gourmand/… d'avant gradins ?

Comment: Vu d'Europe, cela peut ressembler à “[[Un]] piquenique [coffre ouvert][sympa] avant [[une]] rencontre [sportive|autre]” ou “Les piqueniques [coffre ouvert] qui suivent les rencontres/matchs/rendez-vous religieux ou culturels/… [de …]” pour les habitués.

Comment: Le *préludofestivisme* ? >.<

Comment: Hors sujet mais pour moi *tailgate*, ça correspond à "coller au cul"...

Answer (score 1):

> Ce [**genre**](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/genre) de [festivité](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52668/repr%C3%A9sentation-du-nom-d%C3%A9verbal-de-langue-anglaise-lexemple-du-tailgating#comment110194_52668) d'avant-match implique généralement la consommation de boissons alcoolisées ou de sodas et la cuisson de viande.
> La [**pratique**](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/pratique_1) de fêter avant un match s'est ensuite étendue à d'autres festivités d'avant-match lors d'événements sportifs tels que...

En remaniant le terme choisi en complément d'un nom évoquant une catégorie de choses ou un comportement, on peut distinguer du terme au sens strict. Il y a d'autres méthodes possibles et il n'est pas toujours requis de distinguer le nom (*tailgate party*) du déverbal (*tailgating*). Même si l'on sait dans le contexte de l'article que cette « fête » réfère à une notion ou une idée et non pas à un évènement précis au calendrier, le deuxième exemple sans « pratique » créé un léger trompe l’œil vu l'article défini.

Il faut adapter l'hyperonyme au champ lexical du terme et éviter les écueils. Avec des sports, par exemple, le terme *pratique* peut créer une confusion entre la manière habituelle d'agir et le fait d'exercer l'activité.